# What form was the Torah before Sinai

Tags: history, torah-study, kabbalat-hatorah

Chazal say the Torah was studied before Sinai. (ex. by Adam and Eve as explained [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53872/1857). Likewise chazal say the Patriarchs studied Torah from Shem ben Noach.)

In what form was this pre-Torah? It seems it was a different version than the one we have otherwise, they would be reading their own stories and shortcomings which does not make sense.

Comment: The commentaries of the Artscroll says that Jacob studied Torah at the school of Eber.

Comment: Regarding the claim that Adam studied Torah, that is probably just homiletics which should not be confused with history. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4037/8775.

Comment: "Likewise chazal say the Patriarchs studied Torah from Shem ben Noach" Where do they say this?

Comment: Incidentally, the link says nothing about Eve studying Torah; unsurprising give n the Sages generally negative attitude towards female study.

Answer (score 1):

[Shemos Rabbah](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%97) 5:18 says that Bnei Yisroel had scrolls from which they studied Torah in Egypt.
[Rav Zev Wolf of Horadno](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%90%D7%91_%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A3_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9F) (Maharzu) there, says that the scrolls were the entire Bereishis: the stories of Adam, Noah, the Flood, Babel, the Patriarchs and all the prophecies and assurances that were prophesied.

So I guess before Sinai, each generation studied what they inherited from the previous generation.

Comment: This seems unlikely. After all Moshe seems to need to teach them from scratch; they seem to be unfamiliar with God in general; strange for those who had studied the Torah. This is not a shortcoming with your answer, but with the Midrash; or rather with acceptance of it as history rather than homiletics.

Comment: I do not recognize these problems.